# how to remove file_name from Excel sheet after export excel file using datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have 2 buttons Excel and CSV to export into excel and csv sheets respectively for jquery datatable, Till now our jquery datatable data is getting exported and downloaded into an excel and csv files fine. But **my problem** here is after export into excel sheet the file name is also inserted into the first row of excel sheet along with datatable data. I want to remove that file name because as I need only the datatable data.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function () {
       var title = $('#example thead tr:eq(0) th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();

       if(title!="Action"){
          $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
           }
         } );

         var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
              dom: 'Bfrtip',
              buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    title: 'My_Report_'+$('#from_date').val()+'_'+$('#to_date').val()
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csv',
                    title: 'My_Report_'+$('#from_date').val()+'_'+$('#to_date').val() 
                }
              ],
              "bInfo": false,
              fixedHeader: true,
              "iDisplayLength": 100,
          } ); 
});
```

My html Datatable is:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed dataTable no-footer table-bordered" id="example" role="grid" >
              <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>Column1</th>
                   <th>Column2</th>
                   <th>Column3</th>
                   <th>Column4</th>
                   <th>Column5</th>
                   <th>Column6</th>
                   <th>Column7</th>
                   <th>Column8</th>
                   <th>Column8</th>
                   <th>Column10</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
              <tbody>
                <td>---</td>
                -----------
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

**My Problem** is File name as "My_Report_startDate_endDate.xls" is getting inserted into the first row in the exported excel sheet. I want to remove that file name from the excel sheet. CSV file data is getting exported fine. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem. This is how i solved it:

```
buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excel',

 filename:'My_Report_'+$('#from_date').val()+'_'+$('#to_date').val() 
 title:'',
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',

filename:'My_Report_'+$('#from_date').val()+'_'+$('#to_date').val() 
title:'',
            }
          ],
```

Comment: Use 

filename: 'ANY NAME'
title:''

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'filename' instead of 'title'

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function () {
       var title = $('#example thead tr:eq(0) th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();

       if(title!="Action"){
          $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
           }
         } );

         var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
              dom: 'Bfrtip',
              buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    filename: 'My_Report_'+$('#from_date').val()+'_'+$('#to_date').val()
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csv',
                    filename: 'My_Report_'+$('#from_date').val()+'_'+$('#to_date').val() 
                }
              ],
              "bInfo": false,
              fixedHeader: true,
              "iDisplayLength": 100,
          } ); 
});
```

Title means title of the table

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But its not working. This time our application <title> is getting inserted into the first row of excel sheet.

Comment: That row is like title in all columns or what?
If that is happening then it is created by Datatable itself

Comment: yeah you are right that is inserted like title for all columns in the first row but from the second row onwards column titles are also getting inserted properly like Column1 Column2 Column3 along with the values under each respective column. how to fix this?

Comment: There is only one to do this is change the settings in dataTables.buttons.min.js

Otherwise, I think that is not possible

Comment: I am stuck at this, This looks so simple but not getting fixed. How to Fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add filename instead of title and set title null

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function () {
       var title = $('#example thead tr:eq(0) th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();

       if(title!="Action"){
          $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
           }
         } );

         var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
              dom: 'Bfrtip',
              buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    filename: 'My_Report_'+$('#from_date').val()+'_'+$('#to_date').val(),
                    title:''
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csv',
                    filename: 'My_Report_'+$('#from_date').val()+'_'+$('#to_date').val(),
                    title:'' 
                }
              ],
              "bInfo": false,
              fixedHeader: true,
              "iDisplayLength": 100,
          } ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting ***title*** to an ***empty***, first row of title in excel sheet will remove

refer following code

```
 buttons: [{
                extend: 'excel',
                text: '<img src="Content/Images/Excel-Logo.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;"/>',
                tag: 'span',
                title: '',
                init: function (api, node, config) {
                    $(node).removeClass('btn btn-secondary buttons-excel buttons-html5')
                },
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
                }
            }],
```